# ¿Por qué me sale ilegal cuando pongo un break en un else?

Tags: javascript

Quiero hacer que cuando llegue a 4 , se pare la iteración

```
var contador = 0;


if(contadorDerecha <= 4){

 arrowsDerecha.style.visibility = "hidden";
 console.log("se cumplio ")

 

}else{

 
 

 contadorDerecha ++;

 break;

}
```

en la consola, me bota error diciendo esto:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Illegal break statement
```

Comment: échale un vistazo a este enlace:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22549032/illegal-use-of-break-statement-javascript

Comment: ¿Cuál iteración?

Comment: Estás confundiendo el uso de break, la condicion if no crea bucles

Comment: que debo hacer entonces  ? creo un bucle ? y adentro pongo la iteracion  y ese bucle lo pongo en una funcion y lo luego lo llamo ?

Comment: Existen diferentes declaraciones de bucle, revisa este enlace para saber cual escoger según tus necesidades https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Loops_and_iteration. Podría ser un while

Comment: Podrías pasar el código y explicar que deseas hacer con contadorDerecha, así será más fácil ayudarte. Gracias